# Getting an Unauthenticated message while trying to access my register route on my API Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, routes, laravel-sanctum

I'm trying to access my register function with a post route, but when doing so and testing it on Postman, I get the following error:

> "message": "Unauthenticated."

I know some people faced the same issue and posted a question here, but none of the answers solved my problem, for example, if I add '->name('login')' after my route, I'm getting a new error :

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
> POST.
> whereas I'm accessing my route with a POST method.

Any idea why I'm getting that ?

api.php:

```
  <?php
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | API Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
    | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
    | is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
    |
    */
    
    Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });
    
    Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
    
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function() {
        Route::resources([
            'constituencies' => \App\Http\Controllers\ConstituencyController::class,
            'candidates' => \App\Http\Controllers\CandidateController::class,
            'participations' => \App\Http\Controllers\ParticipationController::class,
            'towns' => \App\Http\Controllers\TownController::class,
            'users' => \App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class,
            'vote_centers' => \App\Http\Controllers\VoteCenterController::class,
        ]);
    });
    
    Route::post('/tokens/create', function (Request $request) {
        $token = $request->user()->createToken($request->token_name);
    
        return ['token' => $token->plainTextToken];
    });
```

AuthController.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request) {
        $fields = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|string|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed'
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $fields['name'],
            'email' => $fields['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($fields['password'])
        ]);

        $token = $user->createToken('myapptokken')->plainTextToken;

        $response = [
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $token
        ];

        return response($response,201);
    }
    
}
```

web.php:

```
 <?php
    
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Web Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
    | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
    | contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
    |
    */
    
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
```

RouteServiceProvider.php:

```
 <?php
    
    namespace App\Providers;
    
    use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    
    class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
        /**
         * The path to the "home" route for your application.
         *
         * This is used by Laravel authentication to redirect users after login.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        public const HOME = '/home';
    
        /**
         * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function boot()
        {
            $this->configureRateLimiting();
    
            $this->routes(function () {
                Route::prefix('api')
                    ->middleware('api')
                    ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    
                Route::middleware('web')
                    ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
            });
        }
    
        /**
         * Configure the rate limiters for the application.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        protected function configureRateLimiting()
        {
            RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
                return Limit::perMinute(60)->by($request->user()?->id ?: $request->ip());
            });
        }
    }
```

I'm also using Laravel Sanctum, does it change anything?

Thanks !

UPDATE: Route List:

```
 GET|HEAD        / .................................................................................................................................................................................................................. 
  POST            _ignition/execute-solution ........................................................................................................... ignition.executeSolution › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › ExecuteSolutionController  
  GET|HEAD        _ignition/health-check ....................................................................................................................... ignition.healthCheck › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › HealthCheckController  
  POST            _ignition/update-config .................................................................................................................... ignition.updateConfig › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › UpdateConfigController  
  GET|HEAD        api/candidates ........................................................................................................................................................ candidates.index › CandidateController@index  
  POST            api/candidates ........................................................................................................................................................ candidates.store › CandidateController@store  
  GET|HEAD        api/candidates/create ............................................................................................................................................... candidates.create › CandidateController@create  
  GET|HEAD        api/candidates/{candidate} .............................................................................................................................................. candidates.show › CandidateController@show  
  PUT|PATCH       api/candidates/{candidate} .......................................................................................................................................... candidates.update › CandidateController@update  
  DELETE          api/candidates/{candidate} ........................................................................................................................................ candidates.destroy › CandidateController@destroy  
  GET|HEAD        api/candidates/{candidate}/edit ......................................................................................................................................... candidates.edit › CandidateController@edit  
  GET|HEAD        api/constituencies ............................................................................................................................................. constituencies.index › ConstituencyController@index  
  POST            api/constituencies ............................................................................................................................................. constituencies.store › ConstituencyController@store  
  GET|HEAD        api/constituencies/create .................................................................................................................................... constituencies.create › ConstituencyController@create  
  GET|HEAD        api/constituencies/{constituency} ................................................................................................................................ constituencies.show › ConstituencyController@show  
  PUT|PATCH       api/constituencies/{constituency} ............................................................................................................................ constituencies.update › ConstituencyController@update
  DELETE          api/constituencies/{constituency} .......................................................................................................................... constituencies.destroy › ConstituencyController@destroy  
  GET|HEAD        api/constituencies/{constituency}/edit ........................................................................................................................... constituencies.edit › ConstituencyController@edit  
  POST            api/login ..................................................................................................................................................................................... AuthController@login  
  POST            api/logout ................................................................................................................................................................................... AuthController@logout  
  GET|HEAD        api/participations ............................................................................................................................................ participations.index › ParticipationController@index  
  POST            api/participations ............................................................................................................................................ participations.store › ParticipationController@store  
  GET|HEAD        api/participations/create ................................................................................................................................... participations.create › ParticipationController@create  
  GET|HEAD        api/participations/{participation} .............................................................................................................................. participations.show › ParticipationController@show  
  PUT|PATCH       api/participations/{participation} .......................................................................................................................... participations.update › ParticipationController@update  
  DELETE          api/participations/{participation} ........................................................................................................................ participations.destroy › ParticipationController@destroy  
  GET|HEAD        api/participations/{participation}/edit ......................................................................................................................... participations.edit › ParticipationController@edit  
  POST            api/register ............................................................................................................................................................................... AuthController@register  
  POST            api/tokens/create ..................................................................................................................................................................................................  
  GET|HEAD        api/towns ....................................................................................................................................................................... towns.index › TownController@index  
  POST            api/towns ....................................................................................................................................................................... towns.store › TownController@store  
  GET|HEAD        api/towns/create .............................................................................................................................................................. towns.create › TownController@create  
  GET|HEAD        api/towns/{town} .................................................................................................................................................................. towns.show › TownController@show  
  PUT|PATCH       api/towns/{town} .............................................................................................................................................................. towns.update › TownController@update  
  DELETE          api/towns/{town} ............................................................................................................................................................ towns.destroy › TownController@destroy  
  GET|HEAD        api/towns/{town}/edit ............................................................................................................................................................. towns.edit › TownController@edit  
  GET|HEAD        api/user ...........................................................................................................................................................................................................  
  GET|HEAD        api/users ....................................................................................................................................................................... users.index › UserController@index  
  POST            api/users ....................................................................................................................................................................... users.store › UserController@store  
  GET|HEAD        api/users/create .............................................................................................................................................................. users.create › UserController@create  
  GET|HEAD        api/users/{user} .................................................................................................................................................................. users.show › UserController@show  
  PUT|PATCH       api/users/{user} .............................................................................................................................................................. users.update › UserController@update  
  DELETE          api/users/{user} ............................................................................................................................................................ users.destroy › UserController@destroy  
  GET|HEAD        api/users/{user}/edit ............................................................................................................................................................. users.edit › UserController@edit  
  GET|HEAD        api/vote_centers ................................................................................................................................................... vote_centers.index › VoteCenterController@index
  POST            api/vote_centers ................................................................................................................................................... vote_centers.store › VoteCenterController@store  
  GET|HEAD        api/vote_centers/create .......................................................................................................................................... vote_centers.create › VoteCenterController@create  
  GET|HEAD        api/vote_centers/{vote_center} ....................................................................................................................................... vote_centers.show › VoteCenterController@show  
  PUT|PATCH       api/vote_centers/{vote_center} ................................................................................................................................... vote_centers.update › VoteCenterController@update  
  DELETE          api/vote_centers/{vote_center} ................................................................................................................................. vote_centers.destroy › VoteCenterController@destroy  
  GET|HEAD        api/vote_centers/{vote_center}/edit .................................................................................................................................. vote_centers.edit › VoteCenterController@edit  
  GET|HEAD        sanctum/csrf-cookie .................................................................................................................................................... Laravel\Sanctum › CsrfCookieController@show
```

Kernel.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array<int, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array<string, array<int, class-string|string>>
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            'abilities' => \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\CheckAbilities::class,
            'ability' => \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\CheckForAnyAbility::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array<string, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `php artisan route:list`? And also did you add sanctum middleware to `app/http/Kernel.php` file?

Comment: I Updated the question to put what you asked @SachinBahukhandi

Comment: Why did you comment the middleware for your `api` section?

Comment: I didn't change annything, it was originally commented... and i saw nowhere what that was for.
I've tried to uncomment it but I'm still facing the same issue

Comment: If you see this: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#how-it-works. I also cannot see any middleware protecting the register route. Can you check which all middlewares are being applied on `api/register` route?

Comment: Sure but how can I do that? Sorry I'm pretty new with all this

Comment: Can you verify first the things are collating to the above-provided link? Use `php artisan route:list -v` to get list of the middlewares as well

Comment: Okay so yes, all the middlewares are applied on the register route

Comment: OK Nevermind!!! Qomething was missing, I added it and now everything works perfectly, thank you so much!! I've been stucked on it all day